# How do I handle an error in DataGridView that is NOT caught in DataError?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

With a certain value in one cell, I tab to or click on the next and get a NullReferenceException.

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at System.ComponentModel.ReflectPropertyDescriptor.SetValue(Object component, Object value)
at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.DataGridViewDataConnection.PushValue(Int32 boundColumnIndex, Int32 columnIndex, Int32 rowIndex, Object value)
at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell.SetValue(Int32 rowIndex, Object value)
at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.PushFormattedValue(DataGridViewCell& dataGridViewCurrentCell, Object formattedValue, Exception& exception)
at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.CommitEdit(DataGridViewCell& dataGridViewCurrentCell, DataGridViewDataErrorContexts context, DataGridViewValidateCellInternal validateCell, Boolean fireCellLeave, Boolean fireCellEnter, Boolean fireRowLeave, Boolean fireRowEnter, Boolean fireLeave)
at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts context, Boolean forCurrentCellChange, Boolean forCurrentRowChange)
at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnCellMouseDown(HitTestInfo hti, Boolean isShiftDown, Boolean isControlDown)
at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnCellMouseDown(DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseDown(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Handling DataError doesn't solve it.

```
       private void DecoratedLineItemsGrid_DataError(object sender, DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs e)
        {
            try
...
```

I've considered handling the CellMouseDown myself, but I don't want to interrupt what normally happens. I just want to trap the error.

Suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Please consider posting a [MCVE].

Comment: The grids `DataError` is typically for when invalid values are placed into a cell. Like alpha characters being typed into an `int` column. So the `null` reference may not necessarily trigger the grids `DataError`. Example; if the grid has at least one column and at least one row but the cells value at `Row[0].Cell[0].Value` is `null`… and we try to execute… `string grr = dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();` … this will throw a `null` exception, but the grids `DataError` will not fire. What line of code is throwing the error?

Comment: @JohnG, I do understand a NullReferenceException.

Unfortunately, the error is being thrown in Microsoft code:
System.ComponentModel.ReflectPropertyDescriptor.SetValue(Object component, Object value)

So which value is being set and which component or value is NULL is not something my debugger is revealing to me.

If you look at the posted call stack, you'll see that none of it is code from my application. Every method in the stack is MS-provided.

So the question is how do I get somewhere into that code and trap the error?

Comment: @JohnG, what you say about it not being a data access thing but instead an assignment of a NULL property to something is almost certainly true.

I just can't see where to break into this call stack and trap the error b/c one of the 100k widget records has a NULL in it.

Comment: Hmmm. I have to ask… is the error produced because of some “external” data that is read by your code? Or is the error happening without any data present? You state that … _”I just can't see where to break into this call stack and trap the error b/c one of the 100k widget records has a NULL in it.”_ … This sounds like you have already isolated the problem to the widget records. Would it not be easier to look through the widget records for the null value(s)? It is difficult to suggest an approach since it is not clear what the code is doing.

Comment: Fair enough.  thanks for the suggestion